# Cretae new column in table component of CDE dashboard of pentaho that represents the sum of 2 columns

Tags: pentaho, dashboard

I have a table component of cde with 8 columns. I want to create a new column that represents the sum of column 6 and 7. I try to follow something similar to grand total but I can not do it. some help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can right a javascript function in pre-execution under advance property of table and populate the sum in column where you wanted.

Comment: Thank, but i solved this problem in datasource. There is a field calculated column.